# Computer massively slow. Interrupts through the roof

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, interrupts

For whatever reason, my laptop has become massively slow on basically any operation.  I cranked up the SysInternals Process Explorer and found that the CPU value of Interrupts goes through the roof on pretty much any operation.

What can I do to fix this?

Windows XP with all the latest patches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have a storage device that went off DMA access, check their properties.

Comment: Specifically what should I check?  How should I fix it?

Comment: Right click on My Computer, Properties, Hardware tab, Device Manager, IDE ATA/ATAPI, Primary IDE Channel, Advanced Settings, Transfer Mode needs to be set to DMA.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with ocdecio that it's probably your hard drive, and that's how you set it back to use DMA. Just wanted to add, though - Windows drops you from DMA to PIO access if it has trouble communicating with the drive.  This can happen once in a while to anyone, for no particular reason (sunspots?) - but if you set if back to DMA, and then this happens again in a week or so, your drive is probably failing.

Comment: a flaky or failing drive controller is also a potential cause of this, and can be easily mistaken for a failing drive.

Comment: So can a bad ribbon cable... that's a quick, cheap fix to try.

Comment: Even if you fix the underlying problem, Windows won't automatically re-enable DMA - you need to go through Device Manager as ocdecio suggested.  And you have to reboot for the change to take effect.

Comment: @MT_Head very true on both points.  i never remember to tell people to swap cables, i always have extras lying around if i need to swap one out, and i've rarely had them go bad on me.

Comment: i guess a solid takeaway is this: if Windows drops to PIO, try reenabling.  if it doesn't work, or drops to PIO again before long, start looking for the cause (cable/drive/controller).